On the deprecated xltxtra package
Following this question of mine and the answer by @egreg I would like to ask:

Why is xltxtra harmful nowadays? Does it contain malicious code or something?
What package does @David Carlisle (comment) refer to that is from an unreliable source?


You can open the xltxtra.sty file (kpsewhich xltxtra.sty will tell you where it is if you are using a TeXLive installation) and get some idea of what it does.

I had posted an answer using newunicodechar package, egreg posted the same output but avoiding the use of that package. My comment was a joke comment as the egreg is the author of newunicodechar so the unreliable source that I was refering to was egreg

@DavidCarlisle see my comment at your answer in the older question. The problem was the font and not the ldf file changes!

@yannisl I do not see it that way: the font has not changed, the reason the document worked in old releases and not in more recent ones is that the macros changed.

@DavidCarlisle Didn’t get the joke. Sorry! Now it all makes sense !!

xltxtra  is a very old package from a time before luatex was a viable alternative and before there was xelatex support in the main format.

It loads ifxetex package (itself deprecated now as its a wrapper around iftex) and executes \RequireXeTeX so loading this package necessarily makes the document not portable between engines even though many documents can work unchanged on either lualatex or xelatex.

It has code to support showing hyphens, but the format now has a version of \showhyphens that works in xelatex without needing any package.

It has the definition of a few xetex-specific logos, but there are other logo packages these days (and most documents do not need a logo)

It loads fontspec which is usually needed, but it is better to load fontspec directly as its interface is then usable in lualatex and xelatex.

It has a few helper commands specific to xetex glyph index support which can be directly defined if needed.



Very insightful!! Thanks !!!
